# What is java String compareTo method and What is Java lexicographically

Tags: java, string-comparison

I don't know what the output means? Will anyone help me with this? Please explain me how it works.

```
  public class LastIndexOfExample{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
   String s1="hello";  
   String s2="hello";  
   String s3="meklo";  
   String s4="hemlo";  
   System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2));  
   System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s3));  
   System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s4));  
  }
}
```

Then the output is:
          0
          -5
          -1

Comment: Putting large numbers of '?' in your question does not help you get an answer more quickly. A well written and explained question works best. I have tidied it as best I could for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) javadoc:

> If there is an index at which the two strings differ, the result is
>   the difference between the two char's at the lowest such index

Full Javadoc:

```
    /**
     * Compares this string to the given string.
     *
     * <p>The strings are compared one {@code char} at a time.
     * In the discussion of the return value below, note that {@code char} does not
     * mean code point, though this should only be visible for surrogate pairs.
     *
     * <p>If there is an index at which the two strings differ, the result is
     * the difference between the two {@code char}s at the lowest such index.
     * If not, but the lengths of the strings differ, the result is the difference
     * between the two strings' lengths.
     * If the strings are the same length and every {@code char} is the same, the result is 0.
     *
     * @throws NullPointerException
     *             if {@code string} is {@code null}.
     */
    public native int compareTo(String string);
```

And from the online documentation (link above):

> The result is a negative integer if this String object
>   lexicographically precedes the argument string

Comment: @Vino the index starts from zero - but the result is the "difference between the two chars" (on the first index where they differ) and this "difference" can be negative as well - see the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Anyways tnx.......but i didn't understand....... i don't know how output comes like 0 , -5 , -1 ..........Plz kindly explain me in a brief manner :'(

Comment: `"hello".compareTo("meklo")`: the first index (zero) is the first point where the strings are different. Since "h" is smaller than "m" (the difference is 5 characters: i, j, k, l, m) the result is -5. If you'll run: `"meklo".compareTo("hello")` the result will be "5". Makes sense now ?

Comment: Bro! Tnx a lot :) i understood wid "h" char......."h" is smaller than "m" wid 5 difrnt char ......... But what about remaining characters????????? Here,output comes only for "h" know......Remaining characters??????

Comment: `compareTo` doesn't acknowledge the rest of the characters, only the one in the first position where the strings differ, it's specified in the last paragraph in the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Comment: Now i get it,Tnx mr.alfasin :) I m new to stackoverflow...This is my second question.....Plz help me when i've doubt wid java and android ? will u?

Comment: No need for "mr" :))) glad you got it! and sure, you can ping me anytime by mentioning my handle in the comments: `@alfasin`. Make sure to tag your questions properly (always mention which programming language you're using as well as any additional tags will better target your audience).

Comment: i m blocked here,to ask questions? why it happpeneds for me? it says 3days u r blocked. I've doubt wid Multidimensional Array concept I need your help.I can't able to post the program here @alfasin

Comment: @vino people usually get blocked when they do something that the system detects as "un-welcomed behavior". I'm not sure what is it you specifically did that triggered your suspension - but try to be aware of your behavior as a SO user. Anyways, there's nothing much I can do about it, sorry!

Comment: But i did nothing bro ;'( @alfasin